# spreadsheet shows values for vertices but not for edges or faces

Tags: geometry-nodes, spreadsheet

I run Blender 3.6.4, leave the default cube, click Geometry Nodes.   I add a Viewer Node to the Geometry nodes.    The spreadsheet shows the Vertex data,  but when I look for Edge or Face data the spread sheet shows the correct number of rows but no columns with data.   I have tried setting the Viewer Node to Auto, Edge, Face, Instance and Please_work, all with no luck.

I haven't downloaded a blend file because my problem shows up with literally just a half dozen mouse clicks from start.

(PS - I have changed the Blender theme colors because I have slight visual acuity problems and have difficulty reading white text on black backgrounds.)

[image: The Vertex data shows up nicely, even if Viewer Node is set to EDGES]

[image: The Edges don't show up.]

Comment: For what it's worth it's the same in version 3.5.1 which I still have on this machine but the Face data has a "sharp_face" column with checkboxes. 3.3 shows a single column called "crease" with zeros in each row for Edge data and Face data has "shade_smooth", "material_index" and "normal" data columns.

Comment: As far as I know, the edges hold no information by default unless you store something on them specifically. The position of an edge for example is only stored through the positions of its vertices and will be evaluated as the average between them. And the _Viewer_ node only shows what you have plugged in there... on the vertices for example is no output visible either, the positions are the inherent information stored on the vertices, but there is no column titled "Viewer" which would be the information plugged in there.

Comment: So, if you want the position of the edges, you have to plug in a _Position_ node into the _Viewer_ node. It could be that the input does not automatically change from _Float_ to _Vector_ though, in this case the spreadsheet will show the position as $\frac{x+y+z}{3}$.

Comment: I just checked, indeed for 3.6.2 I also don't have anything for edges, and since there's no screenshot for faces I retract my statement it's a bug.