# I don't see normal direction in the spreadsheet

Tags: spreadsheet

For some reason I don't see the normal direction in the geometry spreadsheet, I tried to add the viewer node, didn't help.
[image]The first screenshot is what I have, and the second one is how it is supposed to be:

enter image description here[image]

Comment: That seems to have disappeared between versions 3.5 and 3.6 for some reason. I'll bet that your second image is from Blender 3.5 or earlier! It seems to be a bug from comments on https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302937/spreadsheet-shows-values-for-vertices-but-not-for-edges-or-faces

Comment: Yes, it was from a YouTube video posted a year ago
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCwujyy89lg&t=91s

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug, if so, it will not be repaired soon as it seems, at least the bug is still present in my 4.0 beta and 4.1 alpha versions. But as I commented under the question which @JohnEason linked to, maybe this is not a bug but intentionally... the _Spreadsheet_ shows data stored in the specific elements in the specific domains (those values are shown even if you have no _Geometry Nodes_ modifier on the object), and things like normals etc. do not need to be stored additionally wasting memory, because they can be evaluated from the position data of the vertices when needed.